# Как работать с формами которые содержат большое количество данных

Tags: java, sql, jpa, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть ли какой то патерн для работы с формами которые содержат большое количество данных которые не реально полностью выгрузить и базы показать пользователю на UI и отравить во внешнюю систему.

**Задача:**
Есть объект который по мимо прочего содержит таблицу с данными. Данных в таблице на столько много что их нельзя все поднять.

- Нужно чтобы пользователь мог открыть этот объект для редактирования. Таблица при этом поддерживает пэйджинг.
- Нужно, чтобы пользователь мог редактировать данные в таблице.
- Нужно, чтобы пользователь мог **сохранить объект после редактирования** или **отменить и не сохранять свои изменения**
- При этом нужна скорость отклика на операцию сохранения результата приемлимая для UI.

Вопрос очень общий. Меня интересует подход. В частности как такое реализовать с реляционной базой данных, а ещё точнее с JPA 2.1

Что я уже пробовал:

1. Версионирование строк в таблице. При редактировании очередной строки в базе создается новая запись с флагом: временная. При отмене операции - они балком удаляются, при сохранении объекта удаляются их старые версии а флаг очищается.
2. При открытии объекта, переносить данные во временное хранилище. И листать из него, но это оказалось неприемлимо долго.
3. Так же были попытки создания временных таблиц.

Поделитесь своими знаниями и опытом по такой проблеме. Может быть есть паттерн или какое нибудь общепринятое решение?

Comment: Можете хранить сам редактируемый объект в отдельном файле и подгружать по ID из базы, когда надо

Comment: И где его хранить и менять до того момента как пользователь нажмет save?

Comment: Я бы хранил в браузере, прямо у пользователя, там же где он и редактирует. Нет смысла отправлять данные на сервер, если пользователь еще не решил, что он хочет сохранять.

Comment: Ну их много. >9000 записей например. На клиент все тащить очень накладно и сохранять потом обратно. Этот этап был пройден самым первым.

Comment: Тащить на клиент надо в любом случае, раз уж пользователь редактирует на стороне клиента. Вопрос только в том, сколько тащить. Можно подгружать по мере надобности. Не думаю, что обычный пользователь сможет редактировать такое количество записей одновременно...

Comment: Нет можно не тащить на клиент. Версия состояние формы может хранится в базе или всессии. Я там перечислил несколько рабочих вариантов, но у них у всех свои ограничения.

Comment: Редактировать пользователь сможет много записей за раз. Например есть кнопка которая делает пересчет всех или части значений балком. В энтерпрайзе такие требования встречаются

Comment: Не думаю, что пользователю будет лучше, если у него перед глазами будет >9000 записей. Он запутается и на его машине кончится ОП :D. А подсчет каких-то общих значения (типа суммы, среднего, тд) можно таки делать на стороне сервера. Это будет удобнее делать, если, например, не ждать, пока клиент нажмет save, а автоматически отправлять **изменения** на сервер каждые несколько секунд.

Comment: Так я и не спорю что все должно бы на сервере. Пользователь видит одну страницу данных. Листает и подгружает другие страницы. Балковые изменения тоже на сервере происходят по команде с клиента. И клиент перерисовывает только ту страницу которая отображена. Вопрос в том как это правильно реализовать если есть требование Save и Cancel?

Answer (score 2):

Описанная вами проблема решается "паттерном" Диалоги (Conversations). Пример “долгоиграющего” диалога:

1. Открывается первый экран диалога. Данные, показываемые пользователю, подгружаются в отдельной сессии Session и БД-транзакции. Пользователь может модифицировать любые поля диалога.
2. После пяти минут редактирования, пользователь использует UI элемент для сохранения. Изменения отразились в БД. Пользователь также ожидает эксклюзивного доступа к данным на время сессии редактирования.

Хотя в описанном примере есть несколько случаев доступа к БД, с точки зрения пользователя, данная серия шагов представляет одну единицу совершенной работы (Unit of Work). Есть множество путей реализации этого в приложении.

Первый (наивный) метод заключается в удержании открытыми сессий Session и транзакции на время редактирования пользователя, с использованием механизмов синхронизации БД для обеспечения эксклюзивного доступа пользователя к редактируемым данным, и предотвращению обращения к ним со стороны других пользователей, гарантируя изоляцию и атомарность. Это анти-паттерн, так как лишняя синхронизация является узким местом при проблемах производительности, встающих в высоконагруженных приложениях.

Другой метод - использование ряда транзакций БД для реализации диалога с БД. В данном случае, обеспечение изоляции бизнес-процессов ложится на плечи приложения. Один диалог обычно покрывает несколько транзакций. Множественные доступы к БД могут быть атомарными, если только одна транзакция (обычно последняя) осуществляет запись в БД. Все другие только читают данные. Типичный путь реализации – через создание wizard-style диалога, покрывающего несколько шагов цикла запрос/ответ. Hibernate включает в себя некоторые возможности, позволяющие реализовать подобный функционал:

- Автоматическое версионирование: Hibernate может осуществлять за вас concurrency-контроль. Он может автоматически обнаружить, осуществлялись ли сторонние обновления данных за время ожидания пользователя.
- Отсоединенные (Detached) объекты: если вы предпочтете использовать шаблон сессия-на-запрос, все загруженные экземпляры будут отсоединены за время ожидания пользователя. Hibernate позволяет вам обратно подсоединить объекты и сохранить модификации. Данный паттерн называется сессия-на-запрос-с-отсоединенными объектами. Автоматическое версионирование используется для изоляции параллельно выполняющихся запросов.
- Расширенная сессия: сессия Session может быть отсоединена от нижележащего JDBC соединения после того, как БД транзакция будет закоммичена, и переподсоединена, когда возникнет новый клиентский запрос. Этот паттерн называется сессия-на-диалог, делающий повторное соединение (reattachment) объектов ненужным. Автоматическое версионирование используется для изоляции параллельных модификаций, при этом сессия не может быть сброшена (flushed) автоматически, только явно.

Т. е. для реализации диалогов в Hibernate можно использовать паттерны Сессия-на-запрос-с-отсоединенным-объектами и сессия-на-диалог.

Для описания паттерна Диалог я использую Hibernate, т. к. в нём точно есть встроенная поддержка паттера и он описан в официальной документации. Про поддержку паттерна в JPA мне говорить сложно, но [быстрое и поверхностное](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/unsychronized-persistencecontext-implement-conversations-jpa/) гугление показывает, что в JPA паттерн реализовать можно.

Источники:

1. [Документация разработчика Hibernate – Глава II. Транзакции и контроль многопоточности](https://habrahabr.ru/post/269485/#2_4_3)
2. [Hibernate ORM User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#long-conversations)
3. [Implementing conversations](http://what-when-how.com/hibernate/implementing-conversations-hibernate/)

В последнем источнике есть примеры различных реализаций паттерна Диалог.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Теперь я знаю что у проблемы даже есть название.

Comment: Меня конечно же интересует вариант с минимальным количеством данных хранящихся в памяти между запросами и быстрым завершением (сохранением).
Получается что это решается несколькими транзакциями на диалог и версионированием измененных данных.